# JavaScript Issue with AddEventlistener function call

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write some simple JS code for estimating the summary price from two values. And then print it out on screen, but it doesn't work with multiple changes and e.t.c.
How should i print out the result?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    window.onload = function() { 
        var take = document.getElementsByClassName("take"); 
        var size1 = document.getElementsByName("size1").value; 
        var size2 = document.getElementsByName("size2").value; 

        take.addEventListener("click", plus, false); 

        function plus() { 
            var result = parseInt(size1)+parseInt(size2); 
            document.getElementsById("summa_order").value = result; 
        } 
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: you should put `var size1 = docum ...` and `size2`  inside the `plus()` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var takes document.getElementsByClassName("take");` results in a NodeList.

To get the items out of it use a loop like:

```
var take = takes[0]
```